# How to use views achieve this

Tags: views, 6

I've two nodes Person and Mission. A Mission can contain many Person's. Now if I'm browsing Person node, then in right side bar block I want to show all Mission's associated with this Person.

Example:

Mission1 contains ( 1 field containing multiple values):

- Person-A
- Person-B

Now if I go and view Person-A then in a block I should see Mission1 as it is associated with it.

Comment: What is the relation between these two node-types?

Comment: Misson contains many Person's

Answer (score 3):

You can use a CCK "node-reference" field. This way you can "link" one mission page on all person pages. After you did this you can easily make a view that gets all persons that are in the mission node...

Maybe you can take a look at:
http://drupal.org/project/Relation